# SQL Server process temp table rows in chunks of 20

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, chunks

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a table variable of which I use it to create JSON strings.

Since I am using the sp_OAMethod which has severe limitation in post size (limited to varchar(4000)),
I want to process my table in chunks of 20 rows, create and send the JSON and carry on looping till the end.

The table has no unique key or something so I cannot come up with an idea that ensures me that the data will be in chunks with any replication or absense.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: If you don't have a primary key (and **why** exactly?? Any table **ought to have** a valid PK!) and no other column or combinations of columns that can properly and uniquely identify rows, then you're not going to get around adding an extra columns (e.g. an `INT IDENTITY`) to make the rows identifyable .....

Comment: By the way, why **are** you using a system that has been out of support for over two years, and was first produced 12 years ago?

Comment: It is not my choice unfortunately @Charlieface